# javascript not loading div in correct fieldset in HTML form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML form where the User enters a numeric value in the field - Number of Sectors (LTE). Upon clicking Generate... new instances of the field-set are created. This functionality is working as expected.

Within each field-set I have 
1. drop down menu - Radio Type... there are 2 possible values - RU or RRU. When the user selects RU I load another hidden div -

```
  <div id="hiddenDiv" style="display:none">
    <label>Details for Radio (RU)</label><br><br>
     Enter Subrack for anchor RU <br>
     <br>
     <input type="text" id="anchor_ru_rack" name="anchor_ru_rack" value=""> 
      <br>
      Enter Slot for anchor RU <br>
      <input type="text" id="anchor_ru_slot" name="anchor_ru_slot" value=""> 
      <br>
   </div>
```

2. Check box- When the user checks that I load some more elements.

Everything works fine if I only have one instance of the field set. When I have more than one instance then for both 1. and 2. the new elements always appear in the first instance of the field-set. What I want is that the new elements should load with the corresponding field-set.

Visit - https://jsfiddle.net/pd7Ln4e3/

Comment: I see different behavior. If I start the fiddle fresh and put a number into the 'Sectors' field and click 'Generate', it creates three fieldsets, but nothing happens when I switch from RRU to RU. If, on the other hand, I switch from RRU to RU before I click 'Generate', I'll see the subtrack fields, but they'll appear on all the new generated fieldsets and not disappear even if I switch back to RRU. But in no case do I see the secondary subtrack fields all appear multiple times within the first instance of the `<fieldset>` tag.

Comment: I believe he's talking about the checkbox only causing that div to show in the first instance. This is because you hard coded the id of that div: onclick="showMe('div2',this)" It is always going to execute for the first instance of 'div2'.

Comment: @dgig. I see what you are saying. Not sure why that is happening

Comment: That happens because you need unique ids for the divs.

Comment: @RyanGibbs - Any suggestions on how can I prevent it from duplicating the first instance and rather use the latest instance div2

Comment: @rfguy The way I would handle it is to write a function that dynamically creates that whole field set, with unique ids for all the controls, rather than cloning your html.

Comment: @RyanGibbs ah, thanks. I misunderstood.